# Firebase: how to generate a unique numeric ID for key?

Tags: push, firebase, unique, identity

I need numeric IDs for human readability. How do I get it in Firebase?

I want numeric ID for keys, e.g. "000000001", "000000002","00000003","00000004".

The reason I need it is because these IDs will become the permanent object ID both online and offline. I want users to be able to browse that object page by just entering URL "/objects/00000001" without efforts.

I am asking here, because I want to know if this can be done without using `.priority`, sub-properties, etc. I guess `set` method can do it somehow. If it is not possible, just tell me no, I can accept that answer.

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Have you tried anything to attempt a solution? Have you read through the Firebase documentation?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

I'd suggest reading through the Firebase documentation. Specifically, see the [Saving Data](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/saving-data.html#section-push) portion of the Firebase JavaScript Web Guide.

**From the guide:**

> #### Getting the Unique ID Generated by push()

> Calling `push()` will return a reference to the new data path, which you can use to get the value of its ID or set data to it. The following code will result in the same data as the above example, but now we'll have access to the unique push ID that was generated

> ```js
> // Generate a reference to a new location and add some data using push()
> var newPostRef = postsRef.push({
>  author: "gracehop",
>  title: "Announcing COBOL, a New Programming Language"
> });
>
> // Get the unique ID generated by push() by accessing its key
> var postID = newPostRef.key;
> ```

*Source: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data#section-ways-to-save*

- A push generates a new data path, with a server timestamp as its `key`. These keys look like `-JiGh_31GA20JabpZBfa`, so not numeric.
- If you wanted to make a numeric only ID, you would make that a parameter of the object to avoid overwriting the generated key.

  - The keys (the paths of the new data) are guaranteed to be unique, so there's no point in overwriting them with a numeric key.
  - You can instead set the numeric ID as a child of the object.
  - You can then query objects by that ID child using [Firebase Queries](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/query/).

*From the guide:*

> In JavaScript, the pattern of calling `push()` and then immediately calling `set()` is so common that we let you combine them by just passing the data to be set directly to `push()` as follows. Both of the following write operations will result in the same data being saved to Firebase:

> ```js
> // These two methods are equivalent:
> postsRef.push().set({
>   author: "gracehop",
>   title: "Announcing COBOL, a New Programming Language"
> });
> postsRef.push({
>   author: "gracehop",
>   title: "Announcing COBOL, a New Programming Language"
> });
> ```

*Source: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data#getting-the-unique-key-generated-by-push*

Comment: It appears `newPostRef.key()` no longer works... `newPostRef.key` does indeed return the key that is generated. It looks like it's directly tied to the property rather than returned from a function called `key()`.

Comment: Just ran into this, had to use '.key' (not a method, but a key), thank you though!

Comment: Any update on this? I tried the mentioned methods but they don't work. The link doesn't work anymore.
Also, current firebase guide to get the ID from push doesn't work either.
I only get Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Comment: @Viet, my answer is quite outdated at this point. I'd recommend comparing my answer to the current documentation.

Comment: @SinanBolel What if I want to use that key as a child id? should I push it again after getting the reference?

Comment: I am for example storing data from another app which has already set ids. So there is a point in having numeric value. And nesting it makes it less quickly searchable. If you have a similar case, know it can be done, see my answer.

Comment: I guess push is going to the server and back? I want the unique ID immediately. I can make one but just wondering if FB had something built in to the client lib

Comment: could someone give an example for `postsRef`? Could that be a reference to a collection?

Answer (score 14):

As explained above, you can use the Firebase default push id.

If you want something numeric you can do something based on the timestamp to avoid collisions

f.e. something based on date,hour,second,ms, and some random int at the end

```
01612061353136799031
```

Which translates to:

```
016-12-06 13:53:13:679 9031
```

It all depends on the precision you need (social security numbers do the same with some random characters at the end of the date). Like how many transactions will be expected during the day, hour or second. You may want to lower precision to favor ease of typing.

You can also do a transaction that increments the number id, and on success you will have a unique consecutive number for that user. These can be done on the client or server side.

(https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write)

Comment: This is not a secure method, as collisions could be made by simply cycling through all possible values. The hash produced by the push method is probably better, although I do not know what algorithm is used.

Comment: @T9b there is no cycling through all possible values, because the date will always go incremental. The push algorithm does pretty much the same.

Comment: Exactly, this is how it is done. Dates and times and nonces are perfectly incremental and that is exactly why it is insecure. As I said you increment through all possible numbers dates and times in the past to break it.

Comment: @T9b secret Id is not always a must, take example of Facebook, you can simply start typing integers to get users profiles (MZ is 4). But you can't really do much more with that data.

Answer (score 3):

Adding to the @htafoya answer.
The code snippet will be

```
const getTimeEpoch = () => {
    return new Date().getTime().toString();                             
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As [the docs](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/saving-data.html#section-push) say, this can be achieved just by using `set` instead if `push`.

As the docs say, it is not recommended (due to possible overwrite by other user at the "same" time).

But in some cases it's helpful to have control over the feed's content including keys.

As an example of webapp in js, 193 being your id generated elsewhere, simply:

```
 firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  var data={
      "name":"Prague"
  };
  firebase.database().ref().child('areas').child("193").set(data);
```

This will overwrite any area labeled 193 or create one if it's not existing yet.

Answer (score -1):

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions

Use transactions and keep a number in the database somewhere that you can increase by one. This way you can get a nice numeric and simple id.