# Firebase convert generated ID to numeric ID

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is an old question but no answers found. Old answers' source links are dead, old functions are deprecated.

I've look at these topics ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28822054/firebase-how-to-generate-a-unique-numeric-id-for-key), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16637035/in-firebase-when-using-push-how-do-i-pull-the-unique-id)) amongst others, and also current [Firebase guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data).

```
function writeUserData(name, win, loss) {
    firebase.database().ref('users/').push({
        name: name,
        wins: win,
        losses: loss
    });
}
```

I need to pull or somehow convert the unique ID from each push to numeric ID: 1, 2

### UPDATE:

Here's what I'm trying to do:

- 2 users can login at the same time from 2 different browsers.
- 1st user hits button 'log-in' or 'start' will be written as `users/1/{user's attributes}` on firebase.
- if there's an existing user
  (*somehow I need to check that on the user-end*), the next user hits
  'start' will be written as `users/2/{user's attributes}` on firebase. Else (no existing user), the user will be written as user1. This is where I think I need `push` instead of `set`. I can use `set` to add more users from 1 browser, but if i open the app from another browser/chrome incognito, the app will just reset the existing users.
- if a user refreshes or closes the browser, that user will be removed from firebase so another user can log-in.

I've tried different methods (loop, creating new var...) to achieve this.

Comment: Why? What is it you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I need numeric ID because I need to update wins and losses after each round. With the generated IDs, I cannot access the data.

Comment: Why can you not access the data?

Comment: This appears to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Using numeric sequential IDs in Firebase Database is most often an anti-pattern. See [this post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html) for more. Cartant is right: tell us what you're trying to accomplish, instead of how you're trying to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than .push, try to use .set or .update. In that way you can set your own generated key. But as already suggested, this may not be the best approach.