# Are there available (exists) Firebase instanceId for PWA?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, progressive-web-apps, instanceid

I'm integrating firebase to my react app and need to generate a unique id for the app with purposes to identify user by this id in the future. After reading firebase docs found that there exist instanceId methods to generate a unique token for iOS and Android.

Question is, are there exist similar methods for generating instanseId for web apps? If no, what methods/packages are you using for these purposes?

I have experience with this npm package [device-uuid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/device-uuid), but maybe you know another best way to do so.

Comment: Don't you get it from firebase itself? Why you need to generate by yourself? https://stackoverflow.com/a/28822372/863110. Also, if you just want to generate guid, https://stackoverflow.com/a/2117523/863110

Comment: Hey, thanks for your comment. As I said in a question I need a unique id for PWA instance that will be stable and I could identify a user using this id in the future. GUID is not stable because every time it returns a new value.

Comment: So when you say `identify user` it's not actually the user but the device..

Comment: That's right! Sorry for the inexactness.

Comment: I can offer to generate guid and store it in `localStorage`. It will not be consistent if the user will clear the site's data though.