# how can write code to store uniqe value in firebase by using angular and ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

we want store uniqe incident id for each incident stored in firebase

## this on server page

add_incident(pro) {

```
console.log(pro)

return this.afs.collection('Incident').add(pro);}
```

## this on addincudent.ts

async savecase(){

let pro = {

```
incidentid:this.incidentid,

civilid:this.civilid,

incidentdate:this.incidentdate,
```

};

```
 if(this.incidentid && this.civilid && this.incidentdate)

{

  const loading= await this.loadingCtrl.create({

    message:"loading---",

    spinner:"crescent",

    showBackdrop:true

  });

  loading.present();
```

this.auth.add_incident(pro).then(resp => {

```
  this.incidentid = "";

  this.civilid = "";

  this.incidentdate = "";

  console.log(resp);

  loading.dismiss();

  this.toast('save Success!','success'); this.router.navigate(['/incidentpage']);

})

  .catch(error => {

    console.log(error);

  });

}
```

Comment: Seems this approach would help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28822054/firebase-how-to-generate-a-unique-numeric-id-for-key

Comment: Please add some description and format code